# Reaction Role Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    if message_id == 728213540858757152:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)
        if payload.emoji.name == "loud_sound":
            role = discord.utils.get(message_id.guild.roles, name="DUYURU")
        elif payload.emoji.name == "bee":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="REKLAM")
        else:
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji.name)

        if role is not None:
            member = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
            if member is not None:
                await member.add_roles(role)
                print(f"{member} {role} aldı!")
            else:
                print("Member not found")
        else:
            print("Role not found")

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    if message_id == 728213540858757152:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)
        if payload.emoji.name == "loud_sound":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="DUYURU")
        elif payload.emoji.name == "bee":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="REKLAM")
        else:
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji.name)

        if role is not None:
            member = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
            if member is not None:
                await member.remove_roles(role)
                print(f"{member} {role} aldı!")
            else:
                print("Member not found")
        else:
            print("Role not found")
```

I am trying to put reaction roles in my discord.py bot, but it doesn't work. It gives me the error: `Role not found`. But I already have the role in my roles list. I tried to use an another role-related code I made that works perfectly, but that didn't work either. I have tried to change `message_id` to `channel` but that didn't work either

Comment: It's obvious that  one of your `discord.utils.get` failed and you get a "Role not found"

Answer (score 0):

A couple of changes, according to the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#event-reference)
`on_reaction_add` has 2 parameters, `reaction, user`, which would change your event listener to `async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user)`

Secondly getting the id of an object is done by doing `object.id`, so you could be doing `guild = reaction.message.guild.id`.

Thirdly, you can use `bot.get_guild(id)` to fetch the guild, but you do not need to do that since you can get it from `reaction.message.guild`.

Comment: No, after changing everything you said, It didn't work

Comment: @Mr.Beanos.-what error are you getting now, is it still Role not found?

Comment: No, it doesn't say anything

Comment: Try adding breakpoints and printing the output. Find out where exactly it's breaking.

Comment: i put print's in every line of code but none of them responded. can you edit the code it should work?